# Changing the signature of a type

Tags: c#, c++, migration

I am C++ programmer, and I am working on a migration project where I need to convert C++ code to C#. I have little knowledge on C#. Also, the migration is 70% complete and is stuck.

During the design phase of the project, people have used "string" as a type for some variables, instead of a class "MultiValue", shown below:

```
class MultiValue
{
    public:
        int valueType;
        double independentValue;
        int index;
        string text;
        .
        .
    // Methods
}
```

Now I am in a position where I have to change the type from "string" to "MultiValue".

My question: is there any code refactoring tool (apart from keyboard, mouse, monitor, coffee, etc. :-P) available for this purpose?

Comment: You mean a tool to change method signatures? What should happen at call-sites (how to create/pass in a `MultiValue` instead of a `string`)? Or do you want to create implicit operators from `string` to `MultiValue`?

Comment: Seems to be to specific for a general refactoring tool. But if you can come up with working refactoring rules then you should use the refactoring tool you forgot to mention (a programmer) and write your custom refactoring.

Comment: I have a suspicion if it's just refactoring, I'm not sure there's an easy solution if only because `string` use is generally pretty wide-spread and you might have issues distinguishing general use from your specific-method use. Maybe just change the method signature to your `MultiValue`, compile, bite the bullet, and work out the errors one by one. How many call sites are we talking about here anyway?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Thanks for the reply, For example, 
string x = "abc"; // already present in the code.
Now have to change 'x' variable to "MultiValue" and then use x.text = "abc";

Comment: Well, you could solve half the problem by adding an implicit conversion operator on MultiValue from string to MultiValue. However, what logic do you see that would know to change "x", specifically? I'm guessing not every string needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper could probably help you get the job done, but it will not do it entirely for you. It is able to find all usage of an object within its scope. Unfortunately, this is as far as it can go.

Using this information though, you will be able to create an enum out of all of the possible outputs it will find and then replace the original variable with it.